# JS - Evaluation with function within switch-case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have objects with ids like `alternative1`, `alternative2` etc. I want to style all of these the same way so I'm trying:

```
    switch (feature.id) {
      case 'marker':
           ...
        break;
      case feature.id.includes('alternative'):
      case 'connectionMarker':
        ... //add styling
        break;
```

This does not seem to work. How could I do this?

Comment: makes zero sense to use a boolean with a case when it does not match the string in the switch. I think you need to rethink your approach. Seems like a switch is the wrong thing to use.

Comment: `swich` uses a [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). that means you need either `true` as `switch` value and checks against the result of a comparison, or take another approach.

Comment: That function call results in a boolean result, so it's as if you had written `case true` or `case false`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423458/use-string-includes-in-switch-javascript-case check this post

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[id^=alternative]").forEach(function() { this.classList.add("alter"); });` OR just css: `[id^=alternative] { color:red }`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple trick:

```
switch (feature.id) {
  case 'marker':
    ...
    break;
  case (feature.id.includes('alternative') ? feature.id : !feature.id):
    // your code here
    break;
  case 'connectionMarker':
    ...
    break;
}
```

Since `feature.id` is always a string value, `!feature.id` will always return false. Hence, if `feature.id` includes "alternative" this line:

```
case (feature.id.includes('alternative') ? feature.id : !feature.id):
```

becomes:

```
case feature.id:
```

which will always be the case (as `feature.id === feature.id`). Otherwise, the line evaluates to:

```
case 0:
```

which will be skipped by the interpreter.