# Angular: Use ngSwitch on String includes?

Tags: angular, angular8

I am writing lot of ngIf statements, rendering an html form, when a product description search contains a keyword.

How do I convert this to ngSwitch?

**Current ngIf statement**

```
<app-store *ngIf="message?.productDescription.includes('Cars')">
     <app-carform></app-carform>
</app-store>
<app-store *ngIf="message?.productDescription.includes('Reading')">
     <app-bookform></app-bookform>
</app-store>
<app-store *ngIf="message?.productDescription.includes('Furniture')">
     <app-homefurnitureform></app-homefurnitureform>
</app-store>
```

**Example ngSwitch:**

I am reading Sample Ngswitch statements, but don't know how to convert the above, if its even possible in angular.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="productDescription">
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'Cars'"><app-carform></app-carform></p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'Reading'"><app-bookform></app-bookform></p>
  <p *ngSwitchCase="'Furniture'"><app-homefurnitureform></app-homefurnitureform></p>
</span>
```

Comment: As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40177408/6139527), you can't. Another alternative would be to move the *if* logic to determine what to be displayed in the component and then you can just call that method when you need it to be displayed on the template.

Comment: It would work but its just a *hack*. IMO, it would be better to move the if-logic to the component and just call that method from the template (html)

Comment: hi @NicholasK or just simple answer in stack paragraph, either is good, appreciate it!

Comment: I guess it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423458/use-string-includes-in-switch-javascript-case

Comment: Just observed that you are calling other components based on your if-blocks. In that case, the best you can do is to extract this portion `message?.productDescription.includes('Cars')` into a method in your component and then invoke that method by passing in a parameter. Not sure if that would work for you.

Comment: hi @NicholasK sure that would work, whatever you think is simple and good coding practice, I am trying to stay away from hack solutions as you mentioned, thanks

Comment: Well, after some more thought, it seems that what you have done initially is fine and there isn't any reason to change your existing approach.

Comment: hi @NicholasK  yeah, always worried that sometimes it could render two components with code maintenance, it should always take the First condition it sees and leave all other conditions alone, thanks, thats what switch statement would do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just read something about custom tricks of the ngSwitch condition, can you try something like that :

```
<div [ngSwitch]="true">
    <app-carform *ngSwitchCase="message?.productDescription.includes('Cars')"></app-carform>
    <app-bookform *ngSwitchCase="message?.productDescription.includes('Reading')"></app-bookform>
    <app-homefurnitureform *ngSwitchCase="message?.productDescription.includes('Cars')"></app-homefurnitureform>
</div>
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45950368/8597732

Answer (score 0):

create function for your switch, for readable and clean code.

```
public  mySelection(selection: string): string {
    switch (selection) {
       case 'gf':
           return 'Gluten-free';
        default:
           return 'Standard';
    }
}
```

In your html

```
<div>
  <p >{{ mySelection('dietSelection') }}</p>
</span>
```

Comment: hi @Poldo, well I need to display application components, you'res is only displaying values, which will not be sufficient for what I'm trying to do, thanks